# Oracle database column data displaying extra decimal value

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g, sqlplus, toad

I have a oracle database table with one column (data type - NUMBER).

The data stored in that column is **1.1**,

But in **Oracle SQL Developer** it is showing as - **1.10000000000000008881784197001252323389**
and when I connect DB using **java (JDBC)** also it is showing same.

When I use **Toad** or **SLQPLUS**(using command prompt) it is showing correct that is 1.1

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you insert this data in the first place ?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it is Oracle that is displaying the number accurately.  That value is the closest 64-bit floating point value to the ideal value `1.1`.  What Toad and SQLPLUS are doing is rounding the actual stored value to the nearest N decimal digits.

I recommend that you read this:

- ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), by David Goldberg.

---

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that what you are doing here is using floating point numbers to represent version numbers.  This is a bad idea. Version numbers are really symbols ... and not numbers that you would perform arithmetic on.  The best idea is to represent them as either character strings, or as pairs / tuples of integers that represent the major no, minor no, patch no, etc.

Treating your package version numbers as symbols will avoid the kind of problem you are having now ... which can be due to the inexact representation issue, or to rounding errors in floating point <-> string conversions.

Answer (score 2):

The data stored in the column is exactly what SQL Developer is showing you. It and JDBC are showing you the actual value, the other clients are not. SQL*Plus and Toad are rounding the number for display. By default SQL*Plus [makes the number fit into 10 characters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2699195) but you can override that with an explicit format mask:

```
create table t42 (package_version number);
insert into t42 values (1.10000000000000008881784197001252323389);

select * from t42;

PACKAGE_VERSION
---------------
            1.1

set numformat 9.99999999999999999999999999999999999999
select * from t42;

                          PACKAGE_VERSION
-----------------------------------------
 1.10000000000000008881784197001252323389
```

Or implicitly [with `set numwidth`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2699209):

```
set numformat ""
set numwidth 40
select * from t42;

                         PACKAGE_VERSION
----------------------------------------
1.10000000000000008881784197001252323389
```

You can use `numwidth` to see the same display change in an SQL Developer worksheet too. The table browser view in your screenshot shows the whole value all the time.

So you need to find out how that number was generated in the first place, and possibly correct it. It looks like a floating-point calculation issue as StephenC suggests, but it isn't obvious why a package version number might have been generated like that for that row, rather than simply being set to exactly `1.1`.